# How to stick/keep-on-top windows default calendar?

Tags: windows-7, calendar

I would like to know, is there any way to keep the windows default calendar on top or like a sticky-window that you see on clicking the date-time in the taskbar (normally, bottom-right of the screen).

Searching on google and superuser doesn't yield any related results.

Comment: The best way to manage your calendar and events by installing a calendar program from another company or you can use Windows Live—programs for your computer and online services that work together. And they're totally free..!

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, since I don't think there is anything special specifically about the OS calendar (compared to others), you can use the Windows 7 gadget!

A search for `Windows 7 gadget calendar` will provide you options, but this link will give you many options http://win7gadgets.com/calendar/

After you install the gadget, it will appear as an always open app. If you right click on the app there is usually an option to set the app to "always on top".

Please note, the gadgets on the link above are all free (I think).

I should point out gadget's an no longer supported due to security risks.